# What is this error mean in Python and XHTML?

Tags: python, xhtml

It keep showing this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zca22/public_html/Lab_Assn_5/Scripts/dice.py", line 7, in <module>
    playerGuess = int(formData["guess"].value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/cgi.py", line 541, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError, key
KeyError: 'guess'
```

I don't know what's wrong iin my code.

```
import cgi
import random

formData = cgi.FieldStorage()
playerName = formData["name"].value
playerGuess = int(formData["guess"].value)
theLength = 5
sum = 0

print "Content-type: text/html"

print "<p>Thanks for playing, " + playerName + ",</p>"

for die in range(theLength):
    val = random.randint(1,6)
    print '<img src = "Images/dice-%i.gif" alt="%i" width="107" height="107" />' % (val, val)
    sum = sum + val

print "<p>You bet the total would be at least " + playerGuess + ". The total rolled was " + sum + ".</p>"

if playerGuess >= sum:
    print "<p>You won!</p>"
else:
    print """<p>Sorry, you lose!</p>
      </body>
      </html>"""
```

Comment: I'm already add this code in XHTML form:   You bet the total will be at least: 
<input type="text" name="guess" size="3" />

Comment: Put the line `fo = open("/tmp/formdata.txt", "w") ; fo.write(repr(formData)); fo.close()` in your code to see what you're actually getting.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not `POST`ing it a `guess` value. You should have something like this in the page before:

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/guess.py" method="post">
    <dl>
        <dt><label for="name_field">Name:</label></dt>
        <dd><input type="text" id="name_field" name="name" required="required" /></dd>
        <dt><label for="guess_field">Guess:</label></dt>
        <dd><input type="number" id="guess_field" name="guess" min="1" max="6" step="1" required="required" /></dd>
    </dl>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Guess" /></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code expects a value for `guess` to be in the form data dictionary, but it's not present.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the form doesn't have a "guess" entry, but it does have a "name" entry.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `"guess"` entry in the `formData`, the dictionary of user inputs. Are you sure you have a field like `<input name="guess" value="3" />` in the exact form you're submitting?

Answer (score 0):

In the Python `dict` dictionary data type, each entry has a **key** and a **value**. Your code `formData["guess"]` tries to access the dictionary `formData` under the key `"guess"` to retrieve the underlying value.

Since you're getting a `KeyError`, your dictionary has no key called `"guess"`. Since the dictionary is populated by your `cgi.FieldStorage()` call, this can be interpreted as saying that your cgi form object has no field with the name "guess".